# Get data from another app

Tags: android

I have two Apps that get data from two different sources. One App gets RFID data and the other App gets data from electric weight. I want to make an App that can get updated data from these two Apps. If new data is retrieved from either one of them, my app will get this data and display it. Can someone please give me some guidance as how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You've asked a general question, so the best I can do is give you a general answer. The only good/android-blessed way to share data between apps is by using a [Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html). Use the content provider to persistently store your data, that way even when one of your apps isn't running, you can still access the information that is saved to the content provider.